# Find m so that $(m+1,1,1)$ , $(1,-m,-1)$ , $(m,1-m,2)$ are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

I formed an augmented matrix    $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}m+1&1&m&0\\1&-m&1-m&0\\1&-1&2&0\end{array}\right)$$
I now that we do reduced row echelon form for the augmented matrix. But do we do the same in this case ? I failed to get the reduced row echelon of this. How can we get the value of m ?

Comment: I would find the determinant of the (non augmented) matrix, set it to 0, and solve for m.

Comment: Why are you augmenting the matrix? That doesn't seem to buy you anyting. In any case, rather than doing Gaussian elimination (which would involve complex expressions and several special cases), it seems to be more straightforward to work out the determinant of the matrix (which will be a second-degree polynomial in $m$) and find which $m$ makes it zero.

Comment: Augmenting a matrix with a column of $0$  adds nothing.

Comment: Ah, I see now -- you're explicitly solving $xv_1+yv_2+zv_3=\vec 0$. True enough, that is part of the _definition_ of a set of vectors being linearly dependent. But here you have a shortcut, because you have the same number of vectors as the dimension of the vector space, so you know the set is linearly dependent if and only if the matrix they make up is _not_ invertible. Hence the suggestion by me and Doug to look at the determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Via the [invertible matrix theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem)

Given a set of $n$ vectors from $\Bbb R^n$, forming a square matrix $A$ using those vectors as the columns we have:

The columns of $A$ are linearly independent $\iff$ $\det(A)\neq 0$

via contrapositive, we have the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent $\iff \det(A)=0$

Calculating the determinant of the matrix we have:

> [$-2m^2-4m$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+of+%7B%7Bm%2B1,1,m%7D,%7B1,-m,1-m%7D,%7B1,-1,2%7D%7D).  By setting that equal to zero it implies...

Answer (score 0):

By row-reducing the matrix, we get

$$ \begin{pmatrix} m + 1 & 1 & m \\ 1 & -m & 1 - m \\ 1 & -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{R_1 \leftrightarrow R_3} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 1 & -m & 1 - m \\ m + 1 & 1 & m \end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{R_2 = R_2 - R_1} \\
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & -m + 1 & -1 - m \\ m + 1 & 1 & m \end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{R_3 = R_3 - (m+1)R_1} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & -m + 1 & -1 - m \\ 0 & m + 2 & -2 - m \end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{R_2 = R_2 + R_3} \\
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 3 & -3 - 2m \\ 0 & m + 2 & -2 - m \end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{R_3 = R_3 - \frac{m+2}{3}R_2}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 3 & -3 - 2m \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3}m(m+2) \end{pmatrix}. $$

Hence, the rows/columns will be linearly independent if and only if $m \neq 0, -2$.